# Implementing KeyValue Observation with issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, key-value-observing

I am trying to implement the Key Value Observation pattern and in most the process have worked well but my newValue and oldValue are same even though the value has changed from old value to new value. Here is the sample code of what I have implemented so far. It will be great if someone can tell me where I have got this wrong.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* selectedRow;
```

Adding Observer

```
 [self addObserver:self
           forKeyPath:@"selectedRow"
              options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld | NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
              context:NULL];
```

Method where value will be updated

```
-(void) methodToChangeValue {
self.selectedRow = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:[selectedCell]];
//Above line is dummy that will get the row for indexPath and set the selected row, I wanted to pass that row to selectRow key

}
```

Observer call

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {

    NSString* oldValue = [change valueForKey:NSKeyValueChangeOldKey];
    NSString *newValue = [change valueForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey];

    NSLog(@" old value %@ and new value %@", oldValue,newValue);
}
```

** Old value and new value are same even though I changed the value from the method.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem are these lines:

```
_selectedRow = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:[selectedCell]];
[self setValue:_selectedRow forKey:@"selectedRow"];
```

Why are you doing this? Why not do it the proper way:

```
self.selectedRow = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:[selectedCell]];
```

If you do it that way, the KVO will work properly. As you have it now, you are setting the instance variable directly (which bypasses KVO) and then you use KVC to set the property to the same value as its own instance variable. Since you are setting the property to its own value, your observer sees the old and new values as the same.

You are also using the wrong data type for `selectedRow`. It needs to be `NSIndexPath` instead of `NSString`. Same for getting the old and new values. Use `NSIndexPath`.

Comment: I have set the _selectedRow based on user selecting the tableViewcell and want to get the old and new value for rows. I am not exactly sure, what I have done there that is wrong.

Comment: Replace the code in your `methodToChangeValue` with just `self.selectedRow = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:[selectedCell]];`. That will trigger the KVO and give you the old and new value.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy. I am still not able to get the oldValue, it is returning null for oldValue even if I change the row, the new value has old value null and new value 3.

Comment: The first time it will be nil. If you change it again, do you get 3 for the old value? Also, have you written your own explicit setter or getter for the property? If you have, that can cause issues.

Comment: Also make sure you never, in any code, directly set or get `_selectedRow`. Always use `self.selectedRow` in your code.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not get 3 as old value if I change to 2 and vice versa if I change back to 3 from 2. I have not set any setter. Thanks

Comment: I just noticed one serious problem with your code. You declared the `selectedRow` property as `NSString *`. But you assign it an `NSIndexPath *`. Use the correct data types.

Comment: I did get the row from NSIndexPath.row and changed it to NSString*. This is my first time implementing KVO and I usually go with Delegation but no option today so had to implement this, I am really stuck here without understanding what can be wrong except those you already pointed out. Still not able to get the old value.